# text selection and qtip or such tooltip

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, qtip2

I am trying to achieve something with `window.getSelection()` method. I wanted to get selected text within a tooltip with some actions such as edit the selected text, or delete the selected text, and add some tags as well as comments to that selection Similar to the [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html) . In x-editable, we can't edit text directly.

http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/ZXPSY/9/ this is the fiddle where I am working with. I tried to get what I wanted through [Annotator](https://github.com/okfn/annotator) but this is not working in IE7 or 8. And this one is difficult to integrate with an asp.net website.

I tried the solution which is mentioned in [Is it possible to show a qtip with a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535028/is-it-possible-to-show-a-qtip-with-a-function-call) but it is not working. another similar question [How to display tooltip next to selected text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569142/how-to-display-tooltip-next-to-selected-text) has no answer or proper solution.

Bootstrap Popover, or qTip2 with custom content or any such other solutions or the fix to current fiddle is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution using jqueryUI dialog. So sharing it. It may helpful to others who are trying to achieve the same.
Need to include jquery and jqueryUI library. Later use the following code and script.

```
<div id="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus aliquam eros non odio fringilla, placerat feugiat turpis gravida. Vivamus ac porttitor metus. Aliquam a facilisis erat. Morbi a nisi nibh. Vestibulum volutpat gravida eros. Ut in tortor at magna gravida consectetur eget at dui. Vivamus eget justo eu libero mattis interdum. Morbi iaculis lorem ut felis commodo accumsan. Phasellus a tristique tellus, at lobortis neque. Proin quis tempus est. Morbi dignissim tempor justo at fringilla. Proin sit amet tortor mattis, euismod est eu, volutpat mauris.</p>
</div>
```

script

```
if (!window.mSelect) {
    mSelect = {};
}
mSelect.Selector = {};
mSelect.Selector.getSelected = function () {
    var txt = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        txt = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        txt = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return txt;
};

mSelect.Selector.mouseup = function () {
    var st = mSelect.Selector.getSelected();
    if (st != '') {
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: 'You selected ' + st,
            buttons: {
                "Add": function () {

                }
            }
        });
    } 
    else {
        alert("select some text");
    }
};
$(function () {
    $('#text').bind("mouseup", mSelect.Selector.mouseup);
});
```

In `add` function, we can post the selected value via ajax.

However, if anybody has a good solution than this one (showing tooltip instead of dialog), please let me know.